# Pulling SQL info into Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, connection-string, vba

I have been able in the past to create connections and pull in whole tables or even just a column or two from SQL into Excel.

Now what I want to for a user to input an ID into a Userform and then the VBA to run SQL code grabbing the cooresponding ID, FirstName, LastName. It should then paste that info into the first blank row of A,B,C on the "Entry" sheet.

I am getting an error on this line of code stating: Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array("OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DBName"), Destination:=Sheets("Entry").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)).QueryTable
```

Most of this I do not understand it is simply some hand me down code that I am trying to re-purpose. The old code which still works is this:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto " _
        , _
        "Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possibl" _
        , "e=False;Initial Catalog=DBName"), Destination:=Range("Database!$A$1")). _
        QueryTable
```

The difference between these is that instead of just dropping it in one set cell with the code pulling over couple hundred thousand lines of data is I want the code to be in the first blank row and only pull over that one record. But each time it runs it needs to go to the next row.

With the old code it made an actual table which I am guessing is related to the fact that at the end it states QueryTable. I would rather just have the data and not the table format. If there is a way to change it to do this that would be great.

Also in the previous version of this the query only pulled from one table and the `.SourceConnectionFile = _` link to the file. The new code will need to link to two tables so there are two files as I was unable to have it make a connection file with two tables selected. If you can help with that as well that would be great.

I am using Excel 2013 Standard and  SQL Server 2012. Please let me know if you need any more info.

---

So This is what I have so far trying the ADO method suggested by @Kyle. The OCR is the variable input from the Userform in previous code. When this runs it gives no error but it paste no data.

```
Sub Code()

    Sheets("Entry").Select

    On Error Resume Next

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=MyUN;Password=MyPW"
objConnection.Open


Objrecordset.Open "Select B.ID, B.Firstname, B.Lastname From TableA as A Join TableB as B on A.ID = B.ID Where A.Cardnumber =" & OCR, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

If Not Objrecordset.EOF Then
    Sheets("Entry").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Objrecordset
    Objrecordset.Close
Else
MsgBox "Did not Work"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I suggest recording a macro while you built this manually (not as a table). Then replace the given id with a variable and set a cell reference to capture the next available row.

Comment: i am not sure how to do this manually. Is that something you can help me with @ScottHoltzman.

Comment: What's the connection between the two tables?

Comment: I would use ADO for this. That's just my preference though.

Comment: [here's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-external-data-to-your-workbook-945f2cbb-d50b-4ee2-bae8-c4c9381000c6) a great place to start, @ChadPortman

Comment: TableA.ID = TableB.ID @Rory

Comment: @Kyle what is a ADO?

Comment: So i tried recreating the connection using both tables this time instead of an error stating it could not be done I got an error stating there was not enough memory and that I should try 64 bit. But I select make a connection only was not even asking it to over anything yet. I am so confused right now

Comment: ADO stand for "Activex Data Objects". It allows you to build connections to external sources. I use this all the time to query databases housed on SQL Servers. You are able to execute a SQL statement directly into a range in your workbook. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677497(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx) to start.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need can you help me build the code I need to get the desired result? @Kyle

Comment: If you take a stab and post back any issues, I'm more than happy to help get your code working. The connection strings are boilerplate, and then it's just executing a SQL string and using a method to get the data in. It can be a little touchy sometimes, but that's where I should be able to help.

Comment: Ok I will see what I can come up with the SQL part I no issues with but this ADO part I dont quite understand.

Comment: Says I need Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library I show several: 2.0,2.1,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,6.1-- Which should I use?

Comment: @Kyle I have added my attempt at ADO from what I found in your links plus some extra googling but I am still lost.

Comment: I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Can you try running a "SELECT *" and seeing if it returns anything? Also, what data type is "A.CardNumber"? Is OCR a public variable that is set when the user clicks run from the userform?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115141/discussion-between-chad-portman-and-kyle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get it to work with this:

```
Sub Code()

    Sheets("Entry").Select

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT B.ID, B.FirstName, B.LastName From Table A Join Table B as B on A.ID = B.ID Where A.CardNumber ='" & OCR & "'" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    With Worksheets("Entry").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing



End Sub
```